# Extract link attributes from string of HTML

Tags: php

What's the best way to extract HTML out of $var?

example of $var

```
$var = "<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</a>"
```

I want

```
$var2 = "http://stackoverflow.com/"
```

example: preg_match();

what else?

Comment: Hi @Alexus, can you provide a little context?

Comment: Alexus, I've posted your solution in my answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of crafting long complicated regex, do it in steps

```
$str = '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> Stack Overflow</a>';
$str = preg_replace("/.*<a\s+href=\"/","",$str);
print preg_replace("/\">.*/","",$str);
```

one way of "non regex", using explode

```
$str = '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> Stack Overflow</a>';
$s = explode('href="',$str);
$t = explode('">',$s[1]);
print $t[0];
```

Comment: what non-regex way this can be accomplished?

Comment: awesome just what i was looking for.. is there a way to put that into one line though? explode part? or is there another way that you don't need any variables at all? like sort of echo (function(function())); and i'd get output i'm seeking for?

Answer (score 5):

If it's a valid HTML string that you have, then the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument) module's [loadHTML()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) function will work, and you can navigate your structure very easily.  This is a good way to do it if you have a lot of HTML to work with.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</a>');
$anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($anchors as $node) {
    echo $node->textContent;
    if ($node->hasAttributes()) {
        foreach($node->attributes as $a) {
            echo ' | '.$a->name.': '.$a->value;
        }
    }
}
```

produces the following:

```
Stack Overflow | href: http://stackoverflow.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

[`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) removes HTML from the value of a variable. The second parameter is useful if you would like to make exceptions, and leave certain tags in, like the `p`aragraph tag.

```
$text = '<p>Paragraph.</p> <!-- boo --> <a href="#">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text); // Paragraph. Other text
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>'); // <p>Paragraph.</p> <a href="#">Other text</a>
```

#### phpQuery

If you want to stay away from Regular Expressions, you could use [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) to handle the value, and then use jQuery-style selectors and methods to get your value:

```
// Bring in phpQuery
require("phpQuery-onefile.php");
// Load up our HTML
phpQuery::newDocumentHTML("<a href='http://sampsonresume.com/'>Homepage</a>");
// Print the HREF attribute of the first Anchor
print pq("a:first")->attr("href"); // http://sampsonresume.com/
```

#### Regex

You can use the following to find the URL:

```
$var = "<a href='http://sampsonresume.com/'>Homepage</a>";
preg_match("(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)",$var,$match);
print $match[0]; // http://sampsonresume.com/
```

Comment: You want only HTML and everything inside?

Comment: I want $var2 to contain URL from href link (I want content of href link)

Comment: what non-regex way this can be accomplished?

Comment: Alexus, which phpQuery. I've updated my answer. I'll get you an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regular expression:

```
\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.])(?:[^\s()<>]+|\([^\s()<>]+\))+(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)|[^`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’\s]))
```

Comment: other then regex aka preg_match();

Comment: Alix, I think he wants to stay away from expressions :(

Comment: what non-regex way this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
preg_match_All("#<a\s[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\'\"]??\s*?(?'path'[^\'\"\s]+?)[\'\"\s]{1}[^>]*>(?'name'[^>]*)<#simU", $html, $hrefs, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($hrefs AS $urls){
 print $urls['path']."<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one once for get value of href attribute

```
$link = 'test <a href="www.something.com">Click here</a> test2 <a href="www.test.com">Click here</a>';
preg_match_all('/<a[^>]+href=([\'"])(?<href>.+?)\1[^>]*>/i', $link, $result);

if (!empty($result)) {
    # Found a link.
    echo $result['href'][0];
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $result['href'][1];
}
```

**Output:-**

```
www.something.com
www.test.com
```